# UIMenuController and labels

Tags: copy, label, tableview, cell, uimenucontroller

I am new on Xcode, I have been looking for good tutorial on how to implement UIMenuController on labels.  Most of what I found is 4 or 2 years ago and is not clear.  Text fields maybe better than labels I am not sure.  What I want to do is:

1) Implement IUMenu in a label/text field which exists inside a cell (tableView).

2) When I click it shows copy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution using Text View and all I needed to do is disable edit.